# Another term for fixing another person's mess?

Tags: synonyms

I am looking for another term/shorter words for 'fixing another person's mess'.
I tried looking it on the internet but to no avail.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: More context is needed. As is, the question appears to be too broad.

Comment: more context and a sentence where the word will be used.   Are you looking for a verb?  a noun?

Comment: any word that is closely related to it will do @Centaurus.. thanks

Comment: To "clean up after" someone may suit, but without context it's nearly impossible to say for certain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While neither the question nor this answer will deepen or broaden the world's knowledge of the English language and its usage, the **phrasal verb**

> ***to clean up after***

fits the request.  MW helpfully supplies this definition:

> *to make a place clean after it has been left dirty or messy by (someone)*
>
> *His mother is always cleaning up after him. You should learn to clean up after yourself.*